# vb.net Stop long running thread without wait and start a new one

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

i want to stop a running thread and immediately start a new one without waiting.
My thread read from a Database and shows (after calculation) the result in the UI. 
If the User click a Button i need to "restart" the thread with other paramters. So i must stop the running thread (without waiting) and restart it.
Here a simple example:

```
Dim mythread As Threading.Thread = Nothing
Dim mythreadCancel As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        If Not mythread Is Nothing Then
            If mythread.IsAlive Then
                mythreadCancel = True
            End If
        End If
        mythread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf threadRunning)
        mythreadCancel = False 'if i set this here, the other thread is not stopping!
        mythread.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub threadRunning()
    Try
        While True
            'long operation on Database
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            If mythreadCancel = True Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'ui operation (if not canceled)
            '....
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BtnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStop.Click
    mythreadCancel = True
End Sub
```

If i set the flag to cancel the thread i need to set it back if i start the next thread.
How can i give only the running thread a flag to abort?

I have also used thread.abort. Works fine but now i have read that i should never do that.

[Edit]

Thanks for the comments. I have now find out to work with token. 
I need threads with STA. It sould work also with Tasks. But STA is more complicated.

```
Dim tokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource()
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        tokenSource.Cancel()
        tokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource()
        Dim mythread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadRunning)
        mythread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        mythread.Start(tokenSource.Token)
     Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadRunning(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        Dim token As CancellationToken = CType(obj, CancellationToken)
        Debug.WriteLine("Task starting")
        While True
            'long operation on Database
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            If token.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Exit Task")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("Task running")
            End If
            'ui operation (if not canceled)
            '....
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This seems to work fine. Is it the correct way?

[/Edit]

Comment: If you want to do this, then you need to look at giving your thread an id or a name that can be identified and then at the point of clicking the button it will find the thread you want to kill and then restart it.  At this point then you should look at working with Tasks and the TaskFactory libraries which is a part of `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace and should give you what you need. Take a look here for more information on it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This link should give you a bit more insight too on how the cancellation should work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx